# Intern functional testing - Clicking on buttons sequentially in a set

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing, intern

I'm working with a set of buttons in my Intern functional test and I'd like to be able to run a test on each button sequentially. My page looks something like the following:

```
<input type="button" text="Button 1" class="myBtn">    
<input type="button" text="Button 2" class="myBtn">    
<input type="button" text="Button 3" class="myBtn">
```

And my test is as follows:

```
return remote
    .findAllByClassName('myBtn')
        .then(function(btns) {
            var btn1 = btns[0];
            return btn1;
        })
        .click()
        .end()
        .then(function(btns) {
            var btn2 = btns[1];
            return btn2;
        })
        .click()
        .end()
        .then(function(btns) {
            var btn3 = btns[2];
            return btn3;
        })
        .click()
        .end()
    .end()
```

What is the proper way of doing this type of iterative test using Intern?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a basic recursive call to iterate over each of the returned buttons in sequence and click them:

```js
return remote
  .findAllByClassName('myBtn')
  .then(function (buttons) {
    var i = -1;

    function next() {
      var button = buttons[++i];
      return button ? button.click().then(next) : null;
    }

    return next();
  })
  .end();
```

Comment: Interesting idea, seems to work well... is there a reason why a simple for loop wouldn't work in this context?

Comment: Because the calls are asynchronous.